# How can I subtract an integer number of seconds from a DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have this table.

[image]

I'd like to add a column which is equivalent to **Time_Record** minus the **Idle_time** which is in seconds and will result to DateTime as well.

Comment: Hint: `DATEADD()`.

Comment: `int`s aren't times, you can't get the difference between `time_record` and `Idle_time` as they are completely different data types. It's like asking for the sum of a `decimal` and `varchar`; what is `10.2 + 'car'`? What are you *really* trying to achieve here? What are your expected results? What have **you** tried to achieve those results? Why didn't they work? Also, please provide data in a consumable format, not an image please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select Idle_ID, Emp_ID, Idle_Time,
  dateadd(ss,-Idle_Time,Time_Record) as StartTime,
  Time_Record as EndTime
  from tbl_Idle;
```

[image]

Comment: If the column is already a `datetime` what's the point of casting? If it's not, blindly casting without specifying a format can lead to errors.

Comment: @SMor whatever helps you sleep at night.

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEADD function to add the seconds as shown here'

```
DATEADD(ss,-Idle_Time,CONVERT(DATETIME,Time_Record))
```

Comment: That's no different than the previous answer, right down to the probably unnecessary `CONVERT` and `CAST`. If the column is already a `datetime` what's the point of casting? If it's not, blindly casting without specifying a format can lead to errors.